# client - searching all services using servbyport() function

Tags: c, client-server

I need to do simple client program, when I add port number and client will be serch all services for this port. Now is problem with segmentation fault in if statement.
How to return all services? In my program it will be return just one, I think.

my code:

```
   int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, n,pol, s;
    int numer;
    char recvline[MAXLINE +1];
    char  p;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct servent *sp;

    if (argc != 3)
        err_sys("Aby uruchomić podaj: klient <Adres IP> <port>");

    s = atoi(argv[2]);
    if((sp = getservbyport(s,NULL)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("port (s): %d \n", s);
            printf("port (sp): %d \n", sp->s_port); //segmentation fault
            err_sys("problem with port");   
        }

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0)
        err_sys("Blad utworzenia polaczenia");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = sp->s_port;
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr)<=0)
        err_sys_kom("Blad konwersji do adresu IP dla %s", argv[1]);

    printf("%s", sp->s_name);
    pol = connect(sockfd, (SA*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    if (pol < 0)
       {
          err_sys_kom("Blad polaczenie z serwerem");
          close(sockfd);
          exit(-1);
       }
    else
        str_cli(stdin, sockfd , 1);

exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (in response to *new new problem* - see comments below):

You probably need to get a list of [protocols](http://linux.die.net/man/5/protocols) and work with those in a loop. The contents of the loop should roughly be:

1. Call [`getprotoent`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getprotoent)
2. If the result is NULL, exit the loop.
3. Else, dig out the protocol name from the returned structure.
4. Use that name as the second argument for `getservbyport`
5. Do what you want to with the result

EDIT (in response to *new problem*):

```
if((sp = getservbyport(s,NULL)) == NULL)
```

So your logic is to read `sp` ONLY IF `sp` is `NULL`. Obviously it will segfault.

It should be:

```
if((sp = getservbyport(s,NULL)) != NULL)
```

But then you will point out *another new problem*:

Why is `sp` NULL?

This could be because (as per the earlier version of my answer), you did an `atoi` on something which was *not* an integer. It could be because of any other reason. We can't say because we don't know what input you give.

---

This following part of the answer was in response to an *old* problem that the OP asked in the *same* question, and has since then chosen to edit over it:

First of all: Since you're using `getservbyport`, you really should read about [services](http://linux.die.net/man/5/services), if you haven't already.

Now on to the error:

[`getservbyport`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyport) is of type:

```
struct servent *getservbyport(int port, const char *proto);
```

You are passing `argv[2]` which is of type `char *` instead of an `int` for `port`.

I believe the user inputs this as an argument in your program?

If you *know* that a `char *` points to a set of characters which *look like* an integer, like "1024", then you can convert it to an integer with [`atoi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/atoi.html).

Do this instead, on the line with the error, when calling `getservbyport`, while making sure you've included `stdlib.h`:

```
getservbyport(atoi(argv[2]),NULL)
```

If `argv[2]` is NOT representable as an integer, you'll get undefined behavior, so maybe, you'll want to check this first.

Comment: I forgot, about atoi function. But is problem with sp structure now. `if((sp = getservbyport(argv[2],NULL)) == NULL)` sp is NULL. And I try in if loop: `printf("%d",sp->s_port);` and i `get segmentation fault` (I hope It's correct my error in english).

Comment: @user1031034 - No I do not understand. When you run into a problem, you should remove ALL parts that are irrelevant to the problem, and share that small program which *compiles* but which also reproduces the problem. Your current code fragment is just a big code fragment. In your comment, you are referring to a loop, and I don't see a loop.

Comment: What I mean is: [Read this](http://sscce.org) and then consider modifying your question so we can understand easily, and so that we can *try your program ourselves*. And I also feel that if this is a new *unrelated* problem, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I forogot what is correctly name of this instruction, and I make mistake ;/ I had mean: in if statement. I eddited my code to current / corect version.

Comment: @user1031034 - I made an edit. However, I feel you are following the wrong approach when asking, re-editing and asking new questions inside the same question. This is not what StackOverflow is for. And it is certainly not a support website. It's a Q&A site for programmers.

Comment: OK, I think I understand that. So for each problem ex: problem with conversion char to int, problem with segmentation fault, etc. I should make a new question, for each problem?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If each problem is leading to a new problem, maybe you should sit back and re-look at what is really wrong. A few minutes spent debugging before asking on StackOverflow are always helpful. The idea is to solve your problem as fast as possible right? StackOverflow might actually slow you down.

Comment: `if((sp = getservbyport(s,NULL)) == NULL)` - in my logic, it's correct. If sp is null, then put err_sys - error, else run. 
I make a test and delete if statment, end err_sys function. So I have: `sp = getservbyport(s,NULL));` And all time is segmantation fault. I use atoi, so you don't now what is in input. I run the program: `./klient.c 127.0.0.1 13` so it will be always integer. When I `printf("port (s): %d \n", s);` is returned correct number: 13. So number of port is correctly...

Comment: I solve the problem :)
I use htons(). `sp = getservbyport(htons(s),NULL);` And work, Is returned service. 
In port 13 I have two services, for tcp and udp. How return all services for this port?

Comment: @user1031034 - If `sp` is NULL, then you cannot read `sp->s_port` (because `sp` points to nothing). So doing that inside `if` is going to eventually, still be a problem.

Comment: I have make this in `if` and work properly :D Now only make reurning all services and I will finish my program :)

Comment: @user1031034 - see EDIT at the top of my answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Everything works properly. Thanks again :)